# How to initlaize HTTP API to in spring boot and kotlin

Tags: spring, http, kotlin

I am trying to know how to integrate spring boot with kotlin project. I am refering to this link:

```
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/
```

however, it demands using the following link

```
https://start.spring.io/#!language=kotlin&type=gradle-project
```

to integrate kotlin and gradle

and this link:

```
https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#command-line
```

to Initializr HTTP API

however the last link is not working and actually it is not clear why i should use it.

the question is, how can i use such link as it is down, is there any alternative??

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is entering https://start.spring.io/ and selecting the needs of your project.

If you already know Spring, it's a very good way to start. And don't need gradle to run, this can be done with maven too.

Comment: i am new to kotlin and spring..can i use spring in android studio...any recommendations on using it+

Comment: i'm more a backend programmer rather than mobile developer, but as far as know you can use Spring Boot with your mobile application. Spring has a Mobile project https://projects.spring.io/spring-mobile/. If you are new to both Spring and Kotlin, i recommend you to write some Hello World applications